# getting the value of child nodes in html

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to get the value of child nodes from html.

What i tried:-

```
$data = $dom->getElementById($identifier);
$node = $data->childNodes;
 foreach($node as $node)
    {
           echo $node->nodeName;
           echo $node->nodeValue;

            }
     }
```

I am able to get all the childnodes values, even if the childtag has no value
 i am getting an empty string.

Is there any way to get values if the tag has a proper value ???

Updated:-

My htmldata:-

```
 <div id="myid"> //I give this id as input
 <h1> Some data 1</h1>
 <script type=".."> google adsense details </script>
 <p class="some class"> </p>
 <div class="some class1"></div>
 <h2>data2</h2>
 <p>SOme more data...blah blah..</p>
 </div>
```

What output i want:-

```
  Some data 1
  data2
  SOme more data...blah blah..
```

WHat i am getting:-

```
  Some data 1
  googleadsense details//i am getting values inside script as well
  //blanc data which includes many spaces of tag p 
  //blanc data which includes many spaces of tag div
  data2
  SOme more data...blah blah..
```

Comment: `($node as $node)` OR `($data as $node)`??

Comment: I changed the code...

Comment: Vote down for what ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, this should work for what you're trying to accomplish:

→ **1st EDIT:** This solution accounts for multiple sub nodes to loop through inside identifier.

→ **2nd EDIT:** This solution accounts for specifying what tags/values you don't want returned.

→ **3rd EDIT:** Took out details intended for original question and really irrelevant to updated question.

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $html = '<div id="myid"> //I give this id as input<h1> Some data 1</h1><script type=".."> google adsense details </script><p class="some class"></p><div class="some class1"></div><h2>data2</h2><p>SOme more data...blah blah..</p></div>';
 $dom->loadHTML( $html ); 

 $identifier = "myid";
 $id_nodes = $dom->getElementById( $identifier );

 foreach( $id_nodes->childNodes as $node ) 
 {
    // Blacklist for what you do not want in your output:
    if( $node->nodeName != "script" && $node->nodeName != "#text" && $node->nodeValue != '' ) {
        echo $node->nodeValue . "<br />";
    }
 }
```

The output of the above script is:

```
Some data 1
data2
SOme more data...blah blah..
```

Comment: You did not get my point........I am trying to access the sub nodes from the html,

Comment: My bad, easy fix though, give me 2 and my post will be updated

Comment: Bit i have edited my question, u can hav a look, u wil get clear idea

Comment: Edited answer again so you get the output you're looking for.

Comment: Almost close enough... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check the value before echo?

```
foreach($data as $node)
{
  if(strlen($node->nodeValue) > 0)
{
  echo $node->nodeName;
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
}
```